# Mutilple functions connected to database

Tags: python-3.x

Today I have learned alot and still learning. I have came to a situation where I have realized that I have created a database with multiple functions that does similar stuff but different queries. However by looking at the code we can see a similar "path" of these functions and I have tried and tried to know how I can actually refactor the duplicated code if its even possible?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
from datetime import datetime

import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

DATABASE_CONNECTION = {
    "host": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "database": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "user": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxx"
}


class QuickConnection:
    """
    Function that connects to the database, waits for the execution and then closes
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.ps_connection = psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONNECTION)
        self.ps_cursor = self.ps_connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
        self.ps_connection.autocommit = True

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.ps_cursor

    """
    TODO - Print to discord when a error happens
    """

    def __exit__(self, err_type, err_value, traceback):
        if err_type and err_value:
            self.ps_connection.rollback()
        self.ps_cursor.close()
        self.ps_connection.close()
        return False


def link_exists(store, link):
    """
    Check if link exists
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """

    sql_query = "SELECT DISTINCT link FROM public.store_items WHERE store=%s AND link=%s;"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        data_tuple = (
            store,
            link
        )

        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, data_tuple)

        # Should return 1 if it exists
        link_exist = ps_cursor.rowcount

    return bool(link_exist)


def links_deactivated(store, link):
    """
    Check if link is deactivated
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """

    sql_query = "SELECT DISTINCT link FROM public.store_items WHERE store=%s AND link=%s AND visible=%s;"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        data_tuple = (
            store,
            link,
            "no"
        )

        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, data_tuple)

        # Should return 1 if link is deactivated
        has_deactivate = ps_cursor.rowcount

    return bool(has_deactivate)


def register_products(store, product):
    """
    Register a product to database
    :param store:
    :param product:
    :return:
    """

    sql_query = "INSERT INTO public.store_items (store, name, link, image, visible, added_date) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        data_tuple = (
            store,
            product["name"].replace("'", ""),
            re.sub(r'\s+', '', product["link"]),
            re.sub(r'\s+', '', product["image"]),
            "yes",
            datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        )

        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, data_tuple)

        # Should return 1 if we registered
        has_registered = ps_cursor.rowcount

    return bool(has_registered)


def update_products(store, link):
    """
    Update products value
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """

    sql_query = "UPDATE public.store_items SET visible=%s, added_date=%s WHERE store=%s AND link=%s;"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        data_tuple = (
            "yes",
            datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"),
            store,
            link
        )

        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, data_tuple)

        # Should return 1 if it has been removed
        has_updated = ps_cursor.rowcount

    return bool(has_updated)


def black_and_monitored_list(store, link):
    """
    Check if the link is already blacklisted or being monitored
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """

    sql_query = "SELECT store, link FROM public.manual_urls WHERE link_type=%s AND link=%s AND store=%s union SELECT store, link FROM public.store_items WHERE link=%s AND store=%s"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        data_tuple = (
            "blacklist",
            link,
            store,
            link,
            store
        )

        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, data_tuple)

        # Should return 1 if it has been removed
        is_flagged = ps_cursor.rowcount

    return bool(is_flagged)


def delete_manual_links(store, link):
    """
    Delete given link
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """

    sql_query = "DELETE FROM public.manual_urls WHERE store=%s AND link=%s;"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        data_tuple = (
            store,
            link
        )
        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, data_tuple)

        # Should return 1 if it has been removed
        has_removed = ps_cursor.rowcount

    return has_removed > 0
    
    
def register_store(store):
    """
    Register the store
    :param store:
    :return:
    """
    if not store_exists(store=store):
        sql_query = "INSERT INTO public.store_config (store) VALUES (%s);"

        with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
            data_tuple = (
                store,
            )

            ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, data_tuple)

            # Should have 1 if it has been added
            has_added = ps_cursor.rowcount

        return has_added > 0

    return False
```

I would appreciate all kind of reviews and specially if there is a way to even shorter the duplicated code as well :)

Comment: Why are your functions not methods on `QuickConnection`?

Comment: @Peilonrayz Im not sure if I could answer you the question but the idea was to open the database -> execute -> close. Thats the idea but why its not a method is not what I can answer :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hard-code `DATABASE_CONNECTION` in your source. The connection parameters need to live outside of it, for configurability and security.

Nearly every comment that you have is more harmful than having no comment at all - this:

```
class QuickConnection:
    """
    Function that connects ...
    """
```

lies about a class being a function, and the others are boilerplate that add no value.

Your pattern to `select distinct`, throw away all the results, count the rows, throw *that* away and boil it down to an existence `bool` needs to change. Instead, ask the database whether anything in a subquery exists using the `exists` clause. Rather than applying a `union` to `black_and_monitored_list`, use `exists(...) or exists(...)`. The following should work, though I can't test it:

```
select exists (
   select 1 from fruit_urls 
   where link=%(link)s and store=%(store)s and link_type=%(type)s
) or exists(
   select 1 from store_items
   where link=%(link)s and store=%(store)s
);
```

Consider replacing your `data_tuples` with a dictionary whose keys correspond to PsycoPG `%(key)s` syntax, for clarity and robustness against reordering errors.

Comment: Hi! 1) Regarding the hard-code. I agree. I will change it into a config file instead.

Comment: 2) I see the comment might be unclear and not correctly done as well. That will be worked on, Thank you very much :) Didnt thought about it

Comment: 3) Regarding the exists. I assume since I have lots of checks where I basically check if its there or not (Either True or False) you mean that I should instead of doing select, to use exists instead to see if its in the DB?

Comment: 4) I was not quite sure how you meant but I assume sometihng like this: ```dict_test = {"keywords": positive_or_negative}
    sql_query = "SELECT keyword FROM public.keywords WHERE filter_type = %(keywords)s;"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:

        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, dict_test)```

Comment: Re. 3: it's not "instead of a select"; it needs both, i.e. `select exists(select ...)`

Comment: re. 4: correct.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to  follow up regarding ```exists(...) or exists(...)``` since the idea here is to check if its either True in one of them. My solution was however to do ```SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT store, link FROM public.fruit_urls WHERE link_type=%(type)s AND link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s 
  UNION 
  SELECT store, link FROM public.store_items WHERE link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s)``` - Are you sure you are able to do it the way you thought? Meaning that I will need the union

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example query.

Comment: Ohhh! I did all the combination but besides that :D Thank you very much! Will go back to my cavemen and work with it!

Comment: Hi! I have now done improvement and I think I would need a final review once again! I really appreciate and I hope I have not disappointed you! https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259255/multiple-functions-connected-to-postgressql