# Multiple functions connected to SQL

Tags: python-3.x, sql

I have created a thread before regarding the similar code review I had before [Previous code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259212/mutilple-functions-connected-to-database/259217?noredirect=1#comment511273_259217) - I have updated a small piece of advice I got from previous answer and I did realized I have forgotten the comments to be added as well as I could add `exists(SELECT 1...)`. However I replaced the code where I use dict instead of tuples :)

The main reason of coding this SQL is mostly for new knowledge and as well to make my script more useful, example that I can re-use those functions in multiple scripts as well. Where I can easily just maintain one script instead of having the same code in multiple scripts.

My biggest concern is that I do see some small potential of refactoring where I could most likely shorter the code even more but here I am, stuck at it and I do believe that there might be a small chance that its not possible but I would love to have another eye for it O.O

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from datetime import datetime

import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

from config import configuration

DATABASE_CONNECTION = {
    "host": configuration.path.database.environment,
    "database": configuration.postgresql.database,
    "user": configuration.postgresql.user,
    "password": configuration.postgresql.password
}


class QuickConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ps_connection = psycopg2.connect(**DATABASE_CONNECTION)
        self.ps_cursor = self.ps_connection.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
        self.ps_connection.autocommit = True

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.ps_cursor

    """
    TODO - Print to discord when a error happens
    """

    def __exit__(self, err_type, err_value, traceback):
        if err_type and err_value:
            self.ps_connection.rollback()
        self.ps_cursor.close()
        self.ps_connection.close()
        return False


def link_exists(store, link):
    """
    Check if link exists
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """

    dict_tuple = {"store": store, "link": link}

    sql_query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM public.store_items WHERE store=%(store)s AND link=%(link)s);"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, dict_tuple)
        return ps_cursor.fetchone()[0]


def register_products(store, product):
    """
    Register a product to database
    :param store:
    :param product:
    :return:
    """

    dict_tuple = {"store": store, "name": product["name"], "link": product["link"], "image": product["image"], "visible": "yes", "added_date": datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")}

    sql_query = "INSERT INTO public.store_items (store, name, link, image, visible, added_date) VALUES (%(store)s, %(name)s, %(link)s, %(image)s, %(visible)s, %(added_date)s);"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, dict_tuple)
        return bool(ps_cursor.rowcount)


def update_products(store, link):
    """
    Update products value
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """

    dict_tuple = {"store": store, "link": link, "visible": "yes", "added_date": datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")}

    sql_query = "UPDATE public.store_items SET visible=%(visible)s, added_date=%(added_date)s WHERE store=%(store)s AND link=%(link)s;"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, dict_tuple)
        return bool(ps_cursor.rowcount)


def black_and_monitored_list(store, link):
    """
    Check if the link is already blacklisted or being monitored
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """

    dict_tuple = {"type": "blacklist", "link": link, "store": store}

    sql_query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM manual_urls WHERE link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s AND link_type=%(type)s) OR EXISTS (SELECT store, link FROM store_items WHERE link=%(link)s AND store=%(store)s);"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, dict_tuple)
        return ps_cursor.fetchone()[0]


def delete_manual_links(store, link):
    """
    Delete given link
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """

    dict_tuple = {"store": store, "link": link}

    sql_query = "DELETE FROM public.manual_urls WHERE store=%(store)s AND link=%(link)s;"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, dict_tuple)
        return bool(ps_cursor.rowcount)


def get_product_data(store, link):
    """
    Get id from database for specific link
    :param store:
    :param link:
    :return:
    """

    dict_tuple = {"store": store, "link": link, "visible": "yes"}

    sql_query = "SELECT id, store, link FROM public.store_items WHERE store=%(store)s AND link=%(link)s AND visible=%(visible)s;"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, dict_tuple)
        product = ps_cursor.fetchone()

        return {"id": product["id"], "store": product["store"], "link": product["link"]}


def get_all_keywords(positive_or_negative):
    """
    Get all keywords
    :param positive_or_negative:
    :return:
    """

    dict_tuple = {"keyword": positive_or_negative}

    sql_query = "SELECT keyword FROM public.keywords WHERE filter_type = %(keyword)s;"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, dict_tuple)
        return [keyword["keyword"] for keyword in ps_cursor]



def store_exists(store):
    """
    Check if the store exists in database
    :param store:
    :return:
    """

    dict_tuple = {"store": store}

    sql_query = "SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM public.store_config WHERE store = %(store)s);"

    with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
        ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, dict_tuple)
        return ps_cursor.fetchone()[0]


def register_store(store):
    """
    Register the store
    :param store:
    :return:
    """
    if not store_exists(store=store):

        dict_tuple = {"store", store}

        sql_query = "INSERT INTO public.store_config (store) VALUES (%(store)s);"

        with QuickConnection() as ps_cursor:
            ps_cursor.execute(sql_query, dict_tuple)
            return bool(ps_cursor.rowcount)

    return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please just delete these:

```
"""
Check if link exists
:param store:
:param link:
:return:
"""
```

I'm guessing that your IDE is creating this template for you, with the expectation that you write meaningful documentation for the parameters and the return value. You haven't done so, and the methods are self-explanatory enough that you should just drop the docstrings entirely. For what it's worth, I find adding PEP484 type hints - i.e. `def link_exists(store: str, link: str) -> bool` (at a guess) - to be more informative anyway.

Consider replacing this:

```
    return ps_cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

with

```
exists, = ps_cursor.fetchone()
return exists
```

as it will throw if you unexpectedly get back more than one result.

`dict_tuple` is not a good name for that variable - it is not a tuple; it's just a dict. And anyway, a more descriptive name would be something like `query_params`.

Your `visible` column is suspicious; it seems to be a string accepting `yes`. You should rewrite it as a boolean in the database.

Are you sure you want to prefix every single table reference with the `public` schema? I find that adds visual noise, and also would make a migration to a different schema more difficult.

`register_store` has a puzzling return value. `False` could either mean that there is already a store in existence - or it could mean that the insert failed and zero rows were updated!

Comment: Appreciate it! I have reworked and very happy with the review once again! thank you!!